# How do I get my flexbox footer to take up the entire space at the bottom?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

There is a pixel or two of white space between the left, right, and bottom of the screen and my footer (see the red scribbles on the image above. How do I get the footer to take up all of this space?

Some things I've tried:

- I created a `margin-left: -10; margin-right:-10;` - this worked but it messes with scrolling because the user can scroll sideways now, which I do not want.

  - I created a bottom `<div>` which had `height: 1;` this worked for the bottom but there has to be a better way than sticking a `<div>` here and it doesn't solve for the sideways white space.

Margins are not applied to the parent element of the footer.

```css
footer {
  background-color: #445077;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="col">
    <a href="" class="privacy_policy">
      <div>Privacy policy</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col" style="justify-content: center;">
    <div class="footer_submit">Subscribe</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col" style="justify-content: flex-end;">
    <a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color:white"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" style="font-size:24px;"></i
        ></a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body` has default margins `8px` (in Chrome at least), set `magrin: 0` to it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

footer {
  background-color: #445077;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="col">
    <a href="" class="privacy_policy">
      <div>Privacy policy</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col" style="justify-content: center;">
    <div class="footer_submit">Subscribe</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col" style="justify-content: flex-end;">
    <a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color:white"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" style="font-size:24px;"></i
        ></a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: ahha! Good to know, this worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

You should upload the rest of your code, maybe something else is causing the problem.

Comment: This worked, thanks! Turns out I only needed to zero out the margin, thanks for the help :)